# Installing gphoto2 to use the python binding not working

Tags: python, compiling

I want to use the Python bindings that are available for gphoto2 and this requires a build from their tarballs.  My first step is simply to build gphoto2 such that it recognizes my camera and thus far I have not been successful.   Everything appears to build successfully, my camera is listed as a type that should be recognized...but it is not.   However, when I install gphotot2 via apt-get it works.

My testing is being done on clean copies of Ubuntu running as VMs to keep libraries from getting intermingled.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output of configure?.

Comment: Javier:  Thanks for the post...but...if I did post the output of configure you would probably notice that I had not bound in USB support!   This was pointed out to me and since I have now installed usblib all is well.  Cheers, Will